# How to use Google Maps Weather Layer with gmaps4rails?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'd like to know how can I turn on the Google Maps Weather Layer in my project?

Comment: I've no idea: it's not in the api doc

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported in the API but a feature request has been made which I suggest you "star" and add your comments to make sure it happens.

[Issue 3555:    Add the new weather layer to API as an overlay](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3555&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)